# How do I use a variable to choose which property of an object to search?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I downloaded some JSON which I've converted into an object. I now need to be able to search the second and third level deep and specify which property to search in a variable.

Here is my code attempt.

```
for (var j = 0; j < currentSnapshot.products.length; j++) {
        currentSnapshot.products[j].[firstLayer]; // Is this line kosher?
        if (secondLayer) {
            for (var i = 0; i < secondLayer.length; i++) {
                secondLayer[i]; // Do something.
            };
        };
    };
```

What is the best way to do this?
Thanks for any help.

It looks the the for . . in with a .hasownproperty is what I'm looking for. How do you make this work for the second layer deep -- the properties of the properties?

Comment: What does the JSON look like? Iterating over object properties is usually done with for..in, though with ES5 implementations you can do `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){ obj[key] });` for own enumerable properties of *obj*.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, for .. in is what I'm looking for. I just need to search the second layer (properties of objects within objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your requirement, but I'll attempt to answer:

```
for (var j = 0; j < currentSnapshot.products.length; j++) {
    var secondLayer = currentSnapshot.products[j][firstLayer];
    if(secondLayer){
        for(var i = 0; i < secondLayer.length; i++) {
            secondLayer[i]; // Do something.
        };
    };
};
```

That is, assuming `firstLayer` already refers to a string which is the property you want to access. This is also assuming that `currentSnapshot.products` is an array of objects and `secondLayer` is also an array.

Also, notice I removed the period in between the square brackets in `.products[j].[firstLayer]`, which is a syntax error.

Comment: I was putting a dot between the brackets "products[j][firstlayer]" That's it. Thanks!